# ¿Es despectivo el uso de "gallego" en Hispanoamérica para referirse a los españoles?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, hispanoamérica, insultos

Yo tenía entendido que en Argentina se usa el término "gallego" para referirse a los nacidos en España o de ascendencia española, y que es un término que se usa de modo amistoso, que no implica desprecio en modo alguno. Se usa además, y esto lo acabo de descubrir, en Antillas, Colombia y Uruguay [según el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IlFjdhI), y además en Bolivia y Paraguay [según el diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gallego).

Sin embargo, he visto que la palabra "gallego" tiene en otros países una connotación peyorativa, dado que en México, Costa Rica, Venezuela y Uruguay (y en Chile en menor medida) significa "persona poco inteligente".

No sé si el uso peyorativo proviene del uso de "gallego" como "español". Así que como español, y exclusivamente desde un punto de vista puramente lingüístico, ¿se usa "gallego" en Hispanoamérica para referirse de forma peyorativa a los españoles? Si es así, ¿en qué países?

Comment: Soy de Colombia y **NUNCA** he oído que se use la palabra "gallego" para referirse a personas nacidas en España. De hecho sencillamente usamos la palabra "**español**".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Lo que sigue es anecdótico pero vale, supongo, como respuesta. "Gallego" en Argentina es, como observaste, sinónimo de "español". Es netamente coloquial y no pertenece a esa clase de "gentilicios alternativos" que pueden ser usados de manera semiformal, como hacen los periodistas deportivos (que aquí a los jugadores y equipos uruguayos les suelen llamar "[charrúas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charr%C3%BAas)"). Puede ser tanto amistoso como peyorativo. Sin ningún aditamento es amistoso o neutro, al menos en intención; otro asunto es cómo lo tome el oyente, que supongo que no será muy bien si el mismo es español pero no gallego.

El "problema" con la palabra "gallego" en este sentido, en Argentina (no sé si en otros países), es que aquí son una tradición los chistes de gallegos, donde el tema unificador es que los gallegos (¿los de Galicia o todos los españoles?) son toscos, ignorantes o estúpidos (de manera inocente). El origen de esta tradición no es claro pero una explicación que suele darse es que una parte importante de la inmigración española a Argentina provino de Galicia y que los inmigrantes eran en su mayoría (como no podía ser de otra forma) gente pobre, campesina, poco instruida, con escasa urbanidad, que naturalmente no iba a encajar muy bien en una ciudad ya grande y con veleidades de capital europea como Buenos Aires (el puerto por donde entraban todos los inmigrantes). El estereotipo del *gallego bruto* puede haberse formado ahí, como se formó (y persiste en cierta medida, mucho menor) en el caso de los italianos.

Es debido a esto que la palabra "gallego" como sinónimo de español, coloquial pero neutra en principio, puede sonar a veces peyorativa por asociación.

Comment: El prototipo de chiste que comentas lo tenemos aquí en España, pero en vez de usar otro país o región de otro país, lo concentramos todo en un pueblo de Huelva, [Lepe](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepe), y así surgen los chistes de leperos. Buenas fresas se cultivan en Lepe, por cierto.

Comment: En la pregunta se indica que en Chile se da esto en menor medida, pero eso es incorrecto: acá en Chile también "gallego" es "bruto". Una buena parte del humor se basa en este personaje y su entonación (que en realidad corresponde al acento castellano). Nuestra base étnica tiene muy poco o casi nada de Galicia, así que ahora, después de leer tu respuesta, entiendo por qué existe el personaje. Lo importamos de Argentina.

Comment: Valdría la pena mencionar a Manolito y a don Manoloy su almacén, de Mafalda

Answer (score 9):

Para agregar información a la buena respuesta de @pablodf76, en el Río de la Plata (Uruguay y Argentina) se utiliza la denominación "gallego" con el mismo significado. En general no tiene para nada un sentido peyorativo sino hasta cariñoso, ya que es común en grupos de amigos que se les diga gallegos a quienes nacieron en España.
Asimismo esta palabra tiene muchas veces una intención cómica, por ejemplo, cuando se indica que una película está traducida a español de España en vez de español neutro, expresando algo como: "La película está en gallego".

Answer (score 4):

Yo hablaba mucho con cubanos en Estados Unidos y sí lo usan como peyorativo para referirse a los españoles.

Es más hay una serie de bromas que se dicen en que el gallego es el tonto. En inglés, el equivalente es hacer bromas de los polacos.

No es decir que siempre en todos dialectos del castellano es peyorativo, pero lo he oído usar así.

Answer (score 2):

En Perú el vocablo "gallego" no se usa para referirse a los españoles ni en sentido peyorativo alguno; solo se usa como gentilicio para los nacidos en Galicia y nada más que para eso.

Indicar que se usa como insulto, en "toda hispanoamérica", es una falacia.
Este tipo de generalizaciones desinforman y manipulan la verdad de los hechos.

Answer (score 1):

En Argentina la palabra Gallego como se ha dicho antes no tiene a priori una connotación negativa o positiva. Recomiendo por ejemplo escuchar el tango Galleguita cantado por Gardel. Los de los cuentos de Gallegos como dijeron por ahí, son en realidad los chiste de Lepe muy famosos en España, que seguramente fueron introducidos por los Españoles inmigrantes y de ahí que se les denomine Chistes de Gallegos. La cuestión de usar el término gallego para referirse al Español no esta clara, pero parecer ser bien antigua, hay algún discurso del Gral San Mar†ín en la década del 10 del siglo xix, que denomina Gallegos a las tropas españolas.

Answer (score 1):

Como dicen en otras respuesta la palabra Gallego en España no es peyorativa. Aquí se utiliza exclusivamente para referirse a alguien nacido en Galicia.

Ahora bien, el problema reside en que actualmente (sobretodo entre los jóvenes) ya se conoce el uso que tiene la palabra Gallego en otros países hispanohablantes y su connotación negativa. Por ende, actualmente si alguien se refiere a los Españoles como "Gallego" no le va a hacer ninguna gracia, por ello recomiendo utilizar Gallego cuando quieras decir que alguien es nacido en Galicia, que es el uso que tiene y no para referirte a los españoles.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

En Cuba el término "gallego" se usaba para todos los españoles en general y sin ninguna connotación negativa, en absoluto.

Me refiero al período comprendido entre 1992 y 2013, período en el que yo viajaba a la Isla con frecuencia. No sé si se seguirá usando actualmente. A mí, me solían llamar "oye tú, gallego!", y siempre con buen tono, de buen rollo.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, Francisco.

Answer (score 1):

En Colombia nunca he visto que se utilice de modo peyorativo. Sin embargo ya he visto como cuatro chistes que van por redes sociales que claramente no son de origen colombiano pues son contados por españoles,  en los que se habla de los gallegos como si fueran los tontos (brutos-inocentes)
Hace años escuché en un programa de humor (tocaría buscarlo), a un español que hablaba de los gallegos como tontos. siendo explícito y haciendo la comparación con los pastusos de Colombia. Fue la primera vez que lo escuché. 
Entonces pensé que era un tema de españoles, no de latinoamericanos.